# Firebase listener returns nil

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can't seem to be able to retrieve the child under the node "Users", I'm trying to put the value returned from the listener in a dictionary and then access it to retrieve the name.

```
 "Users" : {
    "GwXI9G1V0mSim8NGGbH18pjzpby2" : {
      "name" : "youssef abdelsalam",
      "profileImageUrl" : "default",
      "sex" : "Male"
    },
```

this is my firebase database

```
var postData = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    userRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users")

    databaseHandle = userRef?.observe(.value, with: { (DataSnapshot) in


        let post:[String:String]? = DataSnapshot.value! as? Dictionary


        if let actualPost = post!["name"]{
            self.postData.append(actualPost)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("\(actualPost)")
        }

    })


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there may be multiple user nodes under `/Users`, you will need to handle that in your code. The simplest way is to loop over `snapshot.children`:    userRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users")

```
databaseHandle = userRef?.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

    for userSnapshot in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        let post:[String:String]? = userSnapshot.value! as? Dictionary

        if let actualPost = post!["name"]{
            self.postData.append(actualPost)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            print("\(actualPost)")
        }
    }

})
```

Comment: it still displays nothing....an error pops up saying that nil has been found while unwrapping optional at ( post!["name"] ) line.

Comment: You might want to check what values *are* in the dictionary in that case.